# Automatically indent clojure when hitting "o" in VS Code with vim bindings

Tags: visual-studio-code, clojure

I'm using VS Code with vim bindings. When I'm editing clojure code, if I hit "enter" (in edit mode), then the cursor is positioned on the new line at the correct indentation.

However, if I hit "o" in normal mode to start a new line instead, then the cursor starts at column 1.

How can I configure VS Code so that it will indent to the proper location when I hit "o" in normal mode?